# Accessing the cell objects value openpyxl at row level

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to make a hash key of the value in each row of the first column of a spreadsheet, then load the rest of the row values into a dictionary (think that is correct python terminology) but in order to do this I would need to access the value of the row and cell.

I have searched various examples and tutorials, and I have got close to what I want, but seems I can't access the data I need to create a hashkey. I get the error:

```
hashString = row.cell(row=baseincr,column=1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cell'
```

I am failing to access the correct object, but have no idea what type of object I should be using. I have tried using the entire sheet using ".active" to get the entire worksheet, but this also fails with the same error.

```
totalcols = tuple(sheet['A12':'J100'])
baseincr = 0
hashString = ""
dataHash = {hashString:[]}

for row in totalcols:
    baseincr += 1
    hashString = row.cell(row=baseincr,column=1)
    for cell in row:
        dataHash.setdefault(hashString,[]).append(cell.value)
```

OK, I found the solution.

```
for row in totalcols:
    baseincr += 1
    hashString = sheet.cell(row=baseincr,column=1).value
    for cell in row:
        dataHash.setdefault(hashString,[]).append(cell.value)
```

You can directly access the value in the cell by giving the row and column, but it is an attribute of the sheet, not a tuple or row.

Comment: You seem to be making invalid assumptions about the data structures. Have you followed the openpyxl tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I have followed the tutorial, and this one: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/, and this one: https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-read-cell-value-in-openpyxl-in-python/ and this one: https://www.pythonexcel.com/openpyxl-write-to-cell.php and a half a dozen others.  So what is my invalid assumption? I don't know, what I don't know.

Comment: So you haven't looked at the openpyxl docs? There are no such things are row objects.

Comment: Finding the "lack of something" in documentation is difficult. So you're saying it isn't possible to access the value of a cell in a row directly? So what I'm attempting will not work in Python?

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells has all you need to know

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution.

```
for row in totalcols:
    baseincr += 1
    hashString = sheet.cell(row=baseincr,column=1).value
    for cell in row:
        dataHash.setdefault(hashString,[]).append(cell.value)
```

You can directly access the value in the cell by giving the row and column, but it is an attribute of the sheet, not a tuple or row.

Comment: You should edit your question to include this.